# Bold first row of every table in a document using condition

Tags: vba, ms-word

I developed a macro to standardize document formatting. I want to add functionality to bold just the first row of every table in this document. See the code below:

```
Sub TableFormat()
Dim oTbl As Table 'Set variable oTbl
Dim oILShp As InlineShape
For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables 'Applies properties below to all tables
    oTbl.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitFixed 'Allow fixed table width
    With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        oTbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 3 'Set paragraph box 3pt before
        oTbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 3 'Set paragraph box 3pt after
        oTbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle 'Set to single spacing
        oTbl.Range.Rows.HeadingFormat = True 'Repeat table header row
        oTbl.PreferredWidth = .PageWidth - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin 'Set table width to page width
        oTbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter 'Horizontally center text
        oTbl.Range.Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter 'Vertically center text
        oTbl.Range.Font.Size = 9 'Set table font size to 9
        oTbl.Range.Font.Name = "Arial" 'Set table font to Arial
        oTbl.Range.Bold = False 'Unbolded
    End With
Next oTbl
End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to add some code to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is inefficient and your PreferredWidth code would fail in a document with different page layouts, since .PageWidth - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin are all, strictly speaking, Section properties, not document properties. You really should also use Styles for the formatting. Apart from anything else, that also means changing the look of all tables in the document becomes as simple as changing the Style attributes. Try:

```
Sub TableFormat()
Dim oTbl As Table 'Set variable oTbl
With ActiveDocument
  On Error Resume Next
  .Styles.Add Name:="TblFmt", Type:=wdStyleTypeParagraph
  On Error GoTo 0
  With .Styles("TblFmt")
    With .ParagraphFormat
      .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter 'Horizontally center text
      .SpaceBefore = 3 'Set paragraph box 3pt before
      .SpaceBefore = 3 'Set paragraph box 3pt after
    End With
    With .Font
      .Size = 9 'Set table font size to 9
      .Name = "Arial" 'Set table font to Arial
      .Bold = False 'Unbolded
    End With
  End With
  For Each oTbl In .Tables 'Applies properties below to all tables
    With oTbl
      .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitFixed 'Allow fixed table width
      .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
      .PreferredWidth = 100 'Set table width to page width
      .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
      .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True 'Repeat table header row
      .Range.Style = "TblFmt"
      .Rows(1).Range.Style = "Strong"
      .Range.Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter 'Vertically center text
    End With
  Next oTbl
End With
End Sub
```